# How to get ajax data in django views?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to retrieve data from an AJAX call in my Django views using the GET method. However, I am unable to successfully access the data in my views. Additionally, the console.log statements are not producing any output. As a beginner, I would greatly appreciate guidance on how to properly retrieve and handle the data in my Django views and troubleshoot the issue with the console log. Thank you in advance.

```
<span class="test">yes</span>
```

ajax call

```
   <script>
    /*
    On focus out on input nickname,
    call AJAX get request to check if the nickName
    already exists or not.
    */
    $(".test").focusout(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the nickname
        var text = $(this).text();
        // GET AJAX request
        console.log('test hoon')
        console.log(text)

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{% url 'dashboard' %}",
            data: {"text": text},
            success: function (response) {
                // if not valid user, alert the user
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        })
        
    })
</script>
```

Views.py

```
 class Dashboard(TemplateView):
        template_name = "dashboard.html"
    
        def get(self,*args, **kwargs):
            amount = self.request.GET.get('text')
            print("I m here !",amount)
            return render(amount,'dashboard.html',)
```

Comment: Have you implemented jQuery in your project? What does it say in the console?

Comment: @dancingCamel yeah i have and that jquery is working file.

Comment: you can ignore the consoling problem , the main problem is how to get that ajax data in views

Comment: Well can you just tell me how can i get that **yes** which is between the span tag into my django view ,

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to. Can you give some context? You usually pass data from the view to the template, not the other way round...

Comment: `self.request.GET.get('text')` is correct. It must be working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use POST method instead of GET, because you are passing data to views, try this if it will work

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{% url 'dashboard' %}",
        data: {"text": text},
        success: function (response) {
            // if not valid user, alert the user
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
```

then in your views you can access it using `self.request.POST.get('text')`